# Stray end tag head and An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, wordpress, validation, head

I've researched the other topics on the forum and checked almost line by line, but couldn't figure out what was going on.

Funny thing is, if I remove the analytics code and some other scripts) the header is OK, but I'm getting other errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro-RO" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>my website • Știri din Mediaş, Sibiu, Transilvania, România</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/xmlrpc.php" />
<link href="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.7.1 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="my website România -știri de ultima oră, noutăți din administrație, afaceri, turism, oportunități de carieră &amp; multe altele pe mywebsite.ro"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/" />
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+MediasinfoRo/"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="ro_RO" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my website • Știri din Mediaş, Sibiu, Transilvania, România" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my website România -știri de ultima oră, noutăți din administrație, afaceri, turism, oportunități de carieră &amp; multe altele pe mywebsite.ro" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mywebsite.ro/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My website" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="http://www.facebook.com/MediasInfo.ro" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001920351958" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="My website - a description for my page mywebsite.ro"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My website tite"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mywebsitero"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="my website"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@mywebsitero"/>
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="88BFCACEC743AF31169417050FCAC780" />
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "https://www.mywebsite.ro/", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "https://www.mywebsite.ro/?s={search_term}", "query-input": "required name=search_term" } }</script>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="my website &raquo; Feed" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="my website &raquo; Feed Comentarii" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="my website &raquo; Acasă Fluxul pentru comentarii" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/acasa/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='g7-shortcodes-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/plugins/g7-shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300%2C400%2C600%2C700%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C700italic&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext%2Ccyrillic&#038;ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-roboto-condensed-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext%2Ccyrillic&#038;ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main-style-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news-child/style.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flexslider-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news/css/flexslider.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='prettyPhoto-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news/css/prettyPhoto.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='liscroll-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/themes/headline-news/css/jquery.liScroll.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='color-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/?css=1&#038;ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jetpack_css-css'  href='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/jetpack.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/6/10/jwplayer.js?ver=4.0.1'></script>
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://wp.me/PQnM3-xWS' />
<script type="text/javascript">//jwplayer</script>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.mywebsite.ro/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ico.png">
<script>//google</script></head>
<body class="home page page-id-130502 page-template page-template-page-builder-php stretched">
<div id="wrapper">
<header class="top">
<div class="container">..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the tags at the end:

```
</body>
</html>
```